# Bulk converting PSD files with Artboards into PDFs

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm currently looking to bulk convert a whole bunch of PSDs into PDFs.

Each PSD is comprised of no more than 10 individual art boards. I know that I have the option to export them as a PDF when the PSD is open, but the issue is that I have a lot of indivudual PSDs, so it's going to take a long time to do them all manually.

I was wondering if there was a way of making an action that will automate this process?

Thanks for any help, and sorry if this isn't the correct site to ask!

Comment: Have you checked the top 2 Google hits? [One](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KNhhDGg_6E) and [Two](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. This is not a perfect solution as some user interaction will still be required during the batch processing. This is for converting mutli-artboard PSDs to multi-page PDFs.

1. Make sure all your PSDs are in one folder. I assume these are already multi-artboard PSDs.
2. Open one of the images.
3. Begin recording an Action. Name it something like "Artboards2PDF" so you can easily find it again.
4. Do *Select > All Layers*, then *File > Export > Artboards to PDF* and click RUN. Then stop the recording the Action. Close any documents that are open without saving. Open the destination folder on your computer and delete the PDF file which this step created, as you won't need it.
5. Do *File > Automate > Batch*. Choose the Source folder, choose the action you previously recorded, set the destination folder. Click OK.
6. Since the Action utilises a script called "Arboards to PDF", each time the script runs you will be prompted with the Artboards to PDF dialog, and you will have to hit RUN.  After the script completes you will also have to hit OK when it completes each time.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to suppress those script dialogs from appearing. So, this is not a fully automated process (unless someone else can answer that).

Scott's [first link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KNhhDGg_6E) in his comment should help you to create multi-page PDFs from single page PSDs, so I won't answer that.